# SQL CASE STATEMENT to last letter in a string

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a column with the following values:

```
column_1
1223B
123C
028409d
abce
ABCf
```

I want to write a case statement that takes a value of 1 if the last value in the string is lowercase, otherwise 0.

Any suggestions how I can approach this?

**Edit #1:**

The only values that will be found in this column are numbers and letters.

**Edit #2:**

The last character of the string will always be a letter.

Comment: What if it's a number, or a symbol? Or can it only ever be ASCII a-z or A-Z?

Comment: Edited my post to answer that question.

Comment: OK, but that's doesn't say what should happen if the last character is a number?

Comment: Edited again, let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want to handle string that don't end with an uppercase/lowercase character, you could do:

```
case when substr(column_1, -1) = lower(substr(column_1, -1)) then 1 else 0 end
```

or

```
case when substr(column_1, -1) != upper(substr(column_1, -1)) then 1 else 0 end
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ce2e16146f49abe08c36fe39fcd830b4)

The `substr(column_1, -1)` gives you the last character; [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html#GUID-C8A20B57-C647-4649-A379-8651AA97187E):

> If *position* is negative, then Oracle counts backward from the end of *char*.

You can then compare that with the the `lower(...)` (or `upper`) of that and see it if matches.

You could also use a regular expression but that doesn't seem necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `LOWER()` with `SUBSTR()` to find if the last char is lower case. For example:

```
select c, 
  case when lower(substr(c, -1, 1)) = substr(c, -1, 1) 
       then 1 else 0 end as f
from (
  select '1223B' as c from dual
  union all select '123C' from dual
  union all select '028409d' from dual
  union all select 'abce' from dual
  union all select 'ABCf' from dual
) x
```

Result:

```
 C        F 
 -------- - 
 1223B    0 
 123C     0 
 028409d  1 
 abce     1 
 ABCf     1
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e91b22e809f5095807ba21a8ca620567).

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1223B'   from dual union all
  3     select '123C'    from dual union all
  4     select '028409d' from dual union all
  5     select 'abce'    from dual union all
  6     select 'ABCf'    from dual union all
  7     select '1234'    from dual
  8    )
  9  select col,
 10         case when regexp_substr(col, '[[:alpha:]]$') = lower(substr(col, -1)) then 1
 11              else 0
 12         end result
 13  from test;

COL         RESULT
------- ----------
1223B            0
123C             0
028409d          1
abce             1
ABCf             1
1234             0

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```